# Как подключить библиотеку graphics в Python3?

Tags: python, импорт, pip

С помощью pip загрузил на linux библиотеку graphics.py
Далее попытался подключить её к моей программе test.py, написанной на Python3, следующим образом:

```
import graphics
```

Но интерпретатор выдаёт следующую ошибку

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 1, in 
>   import graphics
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphics'

К слову, с помощью команды pip list я убедился, что библиотека graphics.py на компьютере есть. Как её подключить?

Comment: В списке, который выводит `python3 -m pip list`, она есть?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev , команду `python3 -m pip list` ввёл. В появившемся списке graphics.py отсутствует.

Comment: Значит ответ TheSaGe правильный.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, с помощью `pip3 install graphics.py` я добавил эту библиотеку в список, выводимый командой `python3 -m pip list`. После запуска программы интерпретатор вывел на экран следующее `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'` . Как я понял из статей в интернете Tkinter является изначально поставляемой вместе с Питоном библиотекой. Нужно ли мне её скачивать с помощью pip3? Заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: В Python3 название этого модуля начинается с прописной буквы - tkinter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, у вас в системе есть несколько версий пайтона. Если в линуксе одновременно установить python2 и python3, то команда pip будет относиться ко второй версии питона. Попробуйте команду pip3 для вызова пип из третьего питона. Разобраться с версиями помогут команды `which python` и `which pip`